# Which branch does make command work on?

Tags: git, build, makefile, branch, android-source

I am experimenting with AOSP currently and stumbled upon this dilemma. 
Lets take an example of platform/frameworks/base which is one of the many git projects. Say there are multiple local branches for this project i.e. branch1, branch2; Also suppose that I am currently on branch3 in which I cherrypicked some changes. Now, when I give a make command from the root, which branch does it operate on? Meaning that which branch's code is built? Does it build the current branch of every git project automatically?

Answer (score 1):

If `make` does not change which branch to use then the code in the current branches are used.